# Password error at Mac OS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, password

Today I gave my MacBook to my brother. He asked to change name and password. So, I changed all my info. And when I want to unlock to make changes, it shakes (probably error). But I can log in. Can I reset a password without data loss?

Comment: Please clarify what works and what doesn't, which screen etc. you are looking at, what kind of error you get etc. Also, you may want to change your password now that the whole Internet knows :-)

Comment: @patrix it seems pretty clear to me. He changed the password. He can log in at the login screen. However, once logged in, he can't unlock the lock found in the Users & Groups system preference panel.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Feel free to edit the question to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you use multiple keyboard layouts on your Mac - or if you ever did - it's possible that the layout you *think* you're using at login or while logged in is not what you think it is. Try turning on Accessibility and using an onscreen keyboard at login. See if the letters for your password are what you think they are.

I live in France/Switzerland, so a common occurrence is people not aware that their keyboard layout is US, UK, French (France) or French (Swiss). So inevitably, there are lots of "y" and "z" inversions. Sometimes "a"/"q" and "z"/"w" as well.

Additionally, if there are any other Admin users on the system, use one of them to unlock the Users & Groups System Preference.

The last option is to reset the password using System Recovery.

Comment: Okay. I will try resetting using recovery or resetting using Time Machine.

Comment: resetting using Time Machine should be your *last* resort....

Comment: Yes, I am using Chinese keyboard layout.